# how to hide a <div> part from tabs

Tags: html, jquery-ui-tabs, show-hide

i have some `<div id="hideclass">` in jquery tabs.
i want it can hidden or not appear.
i want it can appear after i have click some button.
how do i do that?

Comment: Your selector implies that perhaps using the class attribute is more suitable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
#hideclass{
  display:none;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('#hideclass').show();
});
```

Or you might want to slide toggle it:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('#hideclass').slideToggle();
});
```

Where `#button` is the id of the button which when clicked will show the div eg:

```
<button id="button">
```